# не могу вывести stdout другой программы

Tags: python

Есть код:

```
system = subprocess.Popen([r"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe", "t", filename, f"-p{password}"],
stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = str(system.communicate()[0])
```

Тут я запускаю 7zip и хочу увидеть его работу, он когда работает в cmd (не из питона) - показывает шкалу выполнения в процентах и потом выводит данные которые у меня в output .

Как мне из питона заставить показать как работает 7zip?
Всё работает и так, но невидно процесса. Непонятно висит или нет.

[image: Хочу видеть так]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 1):

У меня получилось только прочитать прогресс из потока `stderr`, по этому поводу ответ есть тут : [EnSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11270524/how-to-print-and-capture-7zips-progress-markers-when-executing-from-python?lq=1)

Во первых необходимо сказать `7z` что бы он писал progress в `stderr`, командой `-bsp2`. Подробнее о команде тут : [-bs (Set output stream for output/error/progress line) switch](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/switches/bs.htm)

Затем я просто в цикле читаю сначала `stdout`, потом `stderr`. Если что то есть из этих двух - вывожу, если ничего нет - выхожу из цикла. Кстати там прогресс он пишет в одну строку разделяя `\r`. Я вывод подправил чтобы он делал вывод построчно!

```
proc = subprocess.Popen([r"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe", "e", r"C:\test123\pycharm-community-2020.2.2.7z",
                             r"-oC:\test123\test", "-aoa", "-bsp2"],
                            stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
    line = proc.stdout.readline()
    if line:
        print(line.rstrip())
    else:
        line = proc.stderr.readline()
        if line:
            progress = list(filter(lambda x: x.strip(), line.decode().split("\r")))
            print("\n".join(progress))
        else:
            break
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не работает в моем случае, не пойму в чем дело. Взял ваш код, переделал под себя, не работает, вернее тестит архив но снова ничего не показывает.

Comment: @SergeyKhripushin версия 7z последняя? что имеено переделываете. попробуйте вначале просто на пролом копипастом посмотреть работает у Вас или нет

Comment: @SergeyKhripushin и размер какой у архива? я специально тестировал на архиве который весит более 100мб, так как иначе он даже может ничего не написать о прогрессе!

Comment: Не работает в моем случае, не пойму в чем дело. Взял ваш код, переделал под себя, не работает, вернее тестит архив но снова ничего не показывает. Взял уже ваш код, как есть, подсунул свой архив, тоже ничего некажет. Вернее показывает все до строки 'Extracting archive.... ' включая эту строку, потом идет разархивация по тихой Как закончит, выводит все остальное, без процентовки соответственно. По коду после первого if встает и ждет когда закончится распаковка, после продолжает работать, соответственно не доходит до показа процентов

Comment: размер 600 метров, последняя версия 7zip

Comment: @SergeyKhripushin сейчас посмотрю

Comment: Вот так точнее будет - line = proc.stdout.readline() вот тут  ждет кода пройдет распаковка

Comment: @SergeyKhripushin попробовал распаралелить и так и сяк. проблема в том что он разом все пишет - весь прогресс. не знаю даже куда копать.

Comment: добавил ответ на свой вопрос. Вот это - "-bsp2" пригодилось. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение:
Дополнительный модуль [subpiper](https://github.com/waszil/subpiper)

from subpiper import subpiper

def my_stdout_callback(line: str):
print(f'STDOUT: {line}')

def my_stderr_callback(line: str):
print(f'STDERR: {line}')

retcode = subpiper(cmd=r'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe x D:\backup\1.7z -oD:\test -aoa -bsp2', stdout_callback=my_stdout_callback, stderr_callback=my_stderr_callback)